# Event grid does not trigger Azure Function when out binding is specified

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

When I upload a file to a storage account container I have an **Event Grid System Topic** to detect this. I have an Event Subscription associated to it, to trigger an **Azure Function** with a binding **in**. At this point everything is working.

However when I add a binding **out** to a cosmos db like this:

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func

def main(event_in: func.EventGridEvent,  doc: func.Out[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    result = json.dumps({
        'id': event_in.id,
        'data': event_in.get_json(),
        'topic': event_in.topic,
        'subject': event_in.subject,
        'event_type': event_in.event_type,
    })

    logging.info('Python EventGrid trigger processed an event: %s', result)

    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
        status_code=200
    )
```

With this binding:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "func.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event_in",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "MyDb",
      "collectionName": "my-files",
      "createIfNotExists": "true",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureCosmosDBConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

the **Event Subscription is sent but directly failed to deliver.** The Function is never triggered.

Here is the error I have from log analytics:

```
outcome=NotFound, latencyInMs=952, id=a7d79278-811f-420d-82c9-c1ab7ad4a4c0, 
outputEventSystemId=13b45faa-7e28-4ee4-bc1b-faea85ceb802, state=FilteredFailingDelivery, deliveryTime=2/27/2023 10:37:59 AM, deliveryCount=6, probationCount=5, 
deliverySchema=EventGridEvent, trackedSystemTopicState=CreatedExplicitlyByUser, 
eventSubscriptionDeliverySchema=EventGridEvent, outputEventFields=InputEvent| 

EventSubscriptionId| DeliveryTime| DeliveryCount| State| Id| ProbationCount| 

LastHttpStatusCode| LastDeliveryOutcome| DeliverySchema| LastDeliveryAttemptTime| SystemId|
 UseMappedResourceArmIdForBilling| TrackedSystemTopicState, outputEventFieldCount=14, 
requestExpiration=1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, delivered=False id=b44393e7-e01e-0002-59d8-
493e1c061d90, inputEventSystemId=4bded2d3-0037-4eaf-8e9e-fa1e93cef82a publishTime=2/26/2023 

11:50:53 AM, eventTime=2/26/2023 11:50:52 AM, eventType=Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated,
 deliveryTime=1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, filteringState=FilteringPending, 
inputSchema=EventGridEvent, publisher=MICROSOFT-STORAGE-STORAGEACCOUNTS.WESTUS-1.EVENTGRID.AZURE.NET, size=796, 

subject=/blobServices/default/containers/files/blobs/file.wav,
 inputEventFields=Id| PublishTime| SerializedBody| EventType| Topic| Subject| FilteringHashCode| SystemId| Publisher| FilteringTopic| TopicCategory| DataVersion|
 MetadataVersion| InputSchema| EventTime| FilteringPolicy, inputEventFieldCount=16, 

type=AzureFunction, subType=NotApplicable, supportsBatching=False, aadIntegration=False,
 managedIdentityType=None, armId=/subscriptions/7dd8/resourceGroups/rg-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-func/functions/EventGridTrigger, 

deliveryResponse=NotFound, errorCode=NotFound, HttpRequestMessage: httpVersion=1.1, 
HttpResponseMessage: HttpVersion=1.1, StatusCode=NotFound(NotFound), StatusDescription=Not
 Found, ConnectionInfo=defaultConnectionLimit=1024, reusePortSupported=True, reusePort=True,
```

It looks like the Event Grid can't find my Azure Function now, is it a limitation of the Event Grid service or did I made a mistake?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@fandro I couldn't reproduce the issue using a similar function to yours.

My setup looks like:

```
Storage Account -> Event Grid Topic -> Event Grid Subscription -> Function -> CosmosDB
```

And this is how the Function's code look like:

`__init__.py`:

```py
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(event: func.EventGridEvent, doc: func.Out[func.Document]):
    result = json.dumps({
        'id': event.id,
        'data': event.get_json(),
        'topic': event.topic,
        'subject': event.subject,
        'event_type': event.event_type,
    })

    logging.info('Python EventGrid trigger processed an event: %s', result)
```

`function.json`:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "TestDB",
      "collectionName": "BlobUploads",
      "createIfNotExists": "true",
      "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that I removed the extra HTTP Response logic which I can't see why it would be needed when triggering the function with Event Grid.
The Function App is running on Linux and uses Python 3.10.

To test the above, I did it on 2 stages:

- first I deployed a basic version without `doc: func.Out[func.Document]` and ensured it works when uploading a new file to the storage account
- then I added `, doc: func.Out[func.Document]`, redeployed, then checked again if this still works. You may need to wait a couple of minutes to see an update in the Monitor tab of the function details.